# How can configure shib.conf when using both SAML sso and password login

Tags: single-sign-on, shibboleth-sp

Already I installed and configured shibboleth in our server for sso login. Whenever I hit any page in my website, it will redirect to my IDP for authentication.
Now I need to implement password login for some external user in the same site without removing sso.

How to I configure the shib.conf file for both sso and password login for same applicaition

Answer (score 1):

Use a dedicated url for sso login (e.g. /login/shibboleth or even a completely different hostname); set only that location as requiring shibboleth authentication, and in the handler for it create whatever kind of session you use just like they'd logged in with a password and redirect to the rest of your website.